# Modifying array values in php Memory exhaust

Tags: php

I have a piece of php code as follows:

```
foreach($collection as $key => $item) {
  $collection[$key]['column'] = 'test';
  $item['column'] = 'test';
}
```

When the collection array has more than 30,000 rows, I get this error PHP Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 89 bytes) .

If I remove the line $collection[$key]['column'], the forloop can finish successfully.

What I cannot understand is that aren't line 2 and line 3 basically the same? They are both changing the same item in the $collection array.

What am i missing here?

Comment: Actually modifying $item would create a copy and modify that, not the $collection (see copy-on-write). So probably php is garbage collecting those $item that aren't used so it doesn't exhaust your memory unlike adding to the collection like on line 2. I suspect if you were to change $item to &$item (causes changes to $item to change $collection) on line 1 you would have the same issue when commenting out line 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question , let us first take a quick look at the [foreach docs](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)

> On each iteration, the value of the current element is assigned to
>   $value and the internal array pointer is advanced by one (so on the
>   next iteration, you'll be looking at the next element).

First let's step up your first question and let's take your second question.

> What I cannot understand is that aren't line 2 and line 3 basically
>   the same?

Actually they are not the same, take those quick examples :

```
$array = ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a'];

foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    $value = 'b';
}

print_r($array);
// Output : Array ( [0] => a [1] => a [2] => a [3] => a )
```

while in the second case :

```
$array = ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a'];

foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    $array[$key] = 'b';
}

print_r($array);
// Output : Array ( [0] => b [1] => b [2] => b [3] => b )
```

so, it's totally clear that in your first case, you had modified some copy value or assigned value so to speak, and did not touched the actual value.

so we can say that -so to speak- foreach as php functions has it's own context, for example :

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    // $value variable will be only visible here
    // within the foreach context
}
echo $value; // will output Undefined variable
```

> They are both changing the same item in the $collection array.

you can say -*or assume*- that you've passed a variable to foreach by value, so php -*as mentioned in foreach docs*- had modified a copy of your array element , not the actual value.

while in second example, you've modified the real value of the array `$array` not just a copy of it.

in my examples context, to modify your array in the place, you will need to pass your variable to foreach [by reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.php) to be able to edit your array value directly , for example :

```
$array = ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a'];

foreach ($array as $key => &$value) {
//                         ^
    $value = 'b';
}

print_r($array);
// Output : Array ( [0] => b [1] => b [2] => b [3] => b )
```

---

let's move to your other question :

> If I remove the line $collection[$key]['column'], the forloop can
>   finish successfully.

this is happens because as mentioned above , you are passing your variable to foreach by value, so for each iteration over your `30,000` array there are three operations php will perform :-

1) copy every element of your array to another place in your memory
2) update this copied element
3) update your collection array

which i think takes more memory that your maximum memory limit.

so, as `Christopher` mentioned in his comment, and as mentioned in [foreach doc page](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) :

> In order to be able to directly modify array elements within the loop
>   precede $value with &. In that case the value will be assigned by
>   reference.

passing your value by reference may reduce the memory usage of your script.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this :

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
```

This is not suggested to be done but in you case it is needed. This will override the default PHP memory limit.

Comment: The op's question was about the differences in assignment that one would cause the memory issue and not the other, rather than to avoid the memory issue altogether...

Comment: But the title states that memory gets exhausted.

Comment: There is a memory leak and to know why is it the person needs to post the entire code.

Comment: yes, but that's just the title. The question presented is at the conclusion of the post.

Comment: Exhausted memory does not necessarily mean memory leak. The author states this condition occurs when adding data to an already large data set.

Comment: It doesnt mean but if adding this line fixes the authro's query then this is a case of memory leak.

Comment: no it just means that memory is limited by the hardware instead of a configured value. Memory leak is about mismanagement of memory not simply using too much. If you add to an array indefinitely you will always hit a limit even though you are not leaking memory.